# find out how many instructions made in the core

Tags: linux, intel

I am running an Intel hyper threading system using Linux OS and I would like to find out if there is a way to know how many instructions (actual work) the core (or the virtual core if it can be done) did for a period of time.

Is there any register that can tell me how much instructions was made?

Comment: You can tell the compiler to output the assembly code of your application and analyze the number of instructions using the `-use-msasm` flag, or you can use tools like ugoren suggested, or Intel's VTune

Answer (score 0):

You can install oprofile (http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/).
When using it, you start sampling, then stop after a while.
Then you can get a report of various CPU counters, one of them is the number of instructions.